# Convert Kelvin into Celsius in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, double, openweathermap

I'm trying to retrieve the temperature from the users current location.

I am using the API from OpenWeatherMap. The problem is, they provide the temperature in Kelvin as default, and I would like it in Celsius.

I understand that I just need to subtract 273.15 from the kelvin value....? But i'm struggling to figure out where to do that.

My code for setting my labels:

```
var jsonData: AnyObject?

func setLabels(weatherData: NSData) {

    do {

        self.jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherData, options: []) as! NSDictionary

    } catch {
        //handle error here

    }

    if let name = jsonData!["name"] as? String {

        locationLabel.text = "using your current location, \(name)"

    }

    if let main = jsonData!["main"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let temperature = main["temp"] as? Double {

            self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", temperature)

        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone help me get this right please, as I'm really not sure where to start, thanks.

Let me know if you need to see more of my code.

Comment: FYI - As of iOS 10 / MacOS Sierra, Apple has introduced a Measurements and Units API into Foundation that handles conversions for you as well as localisation. Link to documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmeasurement and also a free WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/238/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if let kelvinTemp = main["temp"] as? Double {
    let celsiusTemp = kelvinTemp - 273.15
    self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", celsiusTemp)
}
```

or simply

```
self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", temperature - 273.15)
```

Answer (score 8):

**For Swift 4.2**:

Use a Measurement Formatter.

```
let mf = MeasurementFormatter()
```

This method converts one temperature type (Kelvin, Celsius, Fahrenheit) to another:

```
  func convertTemp(temp: Double, from inputTempType: UnitTemperature, to outputTempType: UnitTemperature) -> String {
    mf.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    mf.unitOptions = .providedUnit
    let input = Measurement(value: temp, unit: inputTempType)
    let output = input.converted(to: outputTempType)
    return mf.string(from: output)
  }
```

Usage:

```
let temperature = 291.0
let celsius = convertTemp(temp: temperature, from: .kelvin, to: .celsius) // 18°C 
let fahrenheit = convertTemp(temp: temperature, from: .kelvin, to: .fahrenheit) // 64°F
```

To output the localized temperature format, remove the line `mf.unitOptions = .providedUnit`

Comment: I would say this is the best answer since it uses a native library. Thank you @Marcy!

Answer (score 2):

From the code above, it seems to me the right place to do this would be right after you get the temperature

```
if let temperatureInKelvin = main["temp"] as? Double {
  let temperatureInCelsius = temperatureInKelvin - 273.15
  self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", temperature)
}
```

In the future though, I would probably parse your JSON values in a separate class and store them in a model object which you can call later on.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler example of the above handy function (updated for Swift 5.3) would be something like:

```
func convertTemperature(temp: Double, from inputTempType: UnitTemperature, to outputTempType: UnitTemperature) -> Double {
    let input = Measurement(value: temp, unit: inputTempType)
    let output = input.converted(to: outputTempType)
    return output.value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", temperature - 273.15)
```

or you can do it here (pseudo syntax as I don't know Swift that well):

```
if let temperature = (main["temp"] as? Double) - 273.15 {
    self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", temperature)
}
```